# Tests running forever with knex and mocha

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, forever

So i am using the Knex module with Node to interface my database, which is great, does everything that i need.

However, when i run my unit tests in mocha, then the process continues to run even tho the unit tests are finished.

So i saw someone else that had a similar issue where it was running forever and their solution was to use knex.destroy(). I tried this, which works for one file, but i run my unit tests like npm run test* where it will run any file.. So once the first test runs destroy, the following tests then all fail.

I'm just wondering if this is a case of a unresolved promise that is still running? or a misconfigured knex?

I configured knex like so..

```
'use strict';
const
    config = require('../../config/config');

module.exports = require('knex')({
    client: 'mysql',
    connection: {
        host: config.get('db.host'),
        user: config.get('db.user'),
        password: config.get('db.password'),
        database: config.get('db.database'),
        multipleStatements: true
    },
    pool: {
        min: 0,
        max: 5,
    // debug: true
});
```

And when i need a database item i just call it with db.insert( ... ) etc..

Feels a bit wrong that i don't need to get an instance of Knex?

Hoping someone could give me some pointers about it maybe?

Thanks in advance.
Grant

Comment: Reading up about this a bit more i think it's something to do more with Mocha 4.. I've added an --exit flag to my 'npm run tests --exit' and that seems to be exiting properly now from the tests.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with knex `0.15.2`, pg `7.4.3` and mocha `5.2.0`. Solved it like recommended with `knex.destroy()` after each test method:

```
let knex: Knex
beforeEach(async () => {
  knex = Knex({
    client: 'pg',
    connection: config.postgres.connection_string,
    debug: config.postgres.debug,
    acquireConnectionTimeout: config.postgres.connection_timeout
  })
})    
afterEach(async () => {
  await knex.destroy()
})
```